# How to read stored file using Multer disk storage option (NodeJs)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, multer

I am able to store images in my local disk storage using multer successfully but while using GET method, it throws "Cannot GET /uploads/image-1547436792386" error. I have provided my image-upload.js code below:

```
const multer  = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

module.exports = upload;
```

Service.ts:

```
const imageUpload = require('../services/image-upload');
const singleUpload = imageUpload.single('image');

module.exports = function(app) {
   app.post('/api/image-upload', auth.jwtRefreshToken, imageUploadRoute);
};

function imageUploadRoute(req, res) {
  const userId = req.userId;
  if (typeof userId !== 'string') {
    return res.status(422).json({message: 'Error in UserId'});
  }
  singleUpload(req, res, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(422).send({errors: [{title: 'Image Upload error', detail: err.message}]});
    }
    User.findOne({_id: userId})
        .then((user) => {
          console.log(req.file);
          user.profileImage = req.file.path;
          return user.save()
              .then(() => {
            return res.status(200).send({message: 'Image Uploaded Successfully'});
          })
          .catch(() => {
            return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error in uploading image'});
          });
    })
    .catch(() => {
      return res.status(500).send({message: 'UserId not found'});
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your GET API implementation?.Anyway, below code worked for me to download the files. Please try this.

```
app.get("/download/:name(*)", function (req, res, next) {

  var file = req.params.name;
  var path = '/yourFileLocation' + '/' + file;
  res.download(path, file, function (err) {
   if (err) {
     res.status(500).send({ "error": 'Unexpected error occured.' });
   } else {
     res.send({ "message": 'success' });
   }
  });
});
```

Comment: I am not implementing GET API, i store the location of the file and assign it to the user so when i implement GET function of user details, it will show up.